# How do I add a title to my activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, title

How do I add an activity title to my new activity to be displayed on the action bar?
I already added a title when creating that new activity so where is the problem

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Also you can do that programatically like  setTitle("Title!");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under your activity declaration in your `manifest.xml` add the following :

```
 <activity
        android:name=".YourActivity"
        android:label="Your activity name">
```